# get String value from Jenkins console output

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

In the Jenkins output, I had the following assert error
[image]

but I need to get the String error from the error assert or any text. I'm using I'm My JenkinsFile:

`def matcher = manager.getLogMatcher('.*Delete organization Account failed: *')`

but generates the following error:
[image]

So I just want to check, that the log contains a specific string and if the texts exists make the build failed currentBuild.result = "FAILED", saving the text to send it by slack

Comment: The stacktrace looks like something is going wrong trying to marshall a `java.util.regex.Matcher`.  Is that happening as a result of calling `manager.getLogMatcher(...)`?

Comment: its correct when Im using in the jenkinsFile  matcher = manager.getLogMatcher('.*Delete organization Account failed: *') generates error java.util.regex.Matcher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the condition in below way :

```
 if (manager.logContains('.*Delete organization Account failed:*')) {
          error("Build failed because of Delete organization Account..")    
                }
```

Comment: @Luis Eduardo Blandon Puello does this work for you

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me:

```
import hudson.model.*

node {
    .....

    if (Slack.toBoolean() ) {

        def matcher = manager.getLogMatcher(".*Error.*")
        if(matcher.matches()) {
            pbn=matcher.group(0)
            println pbn
            slack_message = "`BUILD ERROR`: ${pbn} "
            println slack_message
            matcher = null // fix NotSerializableException
            slackSend(channel: "#reports", message: slack_message, color: '#172530');
        } 
    }   
}
```

Comment: I did something similar but have issues with the matcher only finding "Error", not ERROR - it seems it is case sensitive. Do you know how to make the matcher case insensitive?